# compilation error

Tags: drupal, composer

I cannot get composer to install civicrm

I get this error

Continue as root/super user [yes]?

> pre-compile-list: Civi\CompilePlugin\Subscriber\OldTaskAdapter->mapRunner
> pre-compile-list: Civi\CompilePlugin\Subscriber\OldTaskAdapter->mapRunner
> Compiling additional files
> Compile: Generate CCL wrapper functions
> shell-runner: @php -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::template($GLOBALS[\Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::GLOBAL_VAR]);'
> Executing command (CWD): '/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/bin/php' -d allow_url_fopen='1' -d disable_functions='' -d memory_limit='1536M' -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::template($GLOBALS[\Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::GLOBAL_VAR]);'
> Compile: Greenwich CSS (dist/bootstrap3.css)
> shell-runner: @php -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL::copy('''../../bower_components/select2/select2-bootstrap.css''', '''extern/select2/select2-bootstrap.scss''');'
> Executing command (CWD): '/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/bin/php' -d allow_url_fopen='1' -d disable_functions='' -d memory_limit='1536M' -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL::copy('''../../bower_components/select2/select2-bootstrap.css''', '''extern/select2/select2-bootstrap.scss''');'
> shell-runner: @php -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::scss($GLOBALS[\Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::GLOBAL_VAR]);'
> Executing command (CWD): '/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/bin/php' -d allow_url_fopen='1' -d disable_functions='' -d memory_limit='1536M' -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::scss($GLOBALS[\Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::GLOBAL_VAR]);'
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Exception\SassScriptException: $amount: Expected 5% to be within 0% and 1% in /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Exception/SassScriptException.php:30
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Node/Number.php(265): ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Exception\SassScriptException::forArgument('Expected 5% to ...', 'amount')
> #1 /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Compiler.php(8450): ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Node\Number->valueInRange(0, 1, 'amount')
> #2 /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Compiler.php(8459): ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Compiler->libOpacify(Array)
> #3 /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Compiler.php(6193): ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Compiler->libFadeIn(Array, Array)
> #4 /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Compiler.php(3662): ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Compiler->callNativeFunction('fadein', Array, NULL, Array)
> #5 /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Compiler.php(3588): ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Compiler->fncall(Array, Array)
> #6 /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Compiler.php(2928): ScssPhp\ScssPhp in /var/www/html/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/src/Compiler.php on line 553
> Script @php -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::scss($GLOBALS[\Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::GLOBAL_VAR]);' handling the shell-runner event returned with error code 255

Comment: See related question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40368/drupal-9-civicrm-compilation-error

Comment: Thanks for your post. It would be helpful, if you could include information about your CiviCRM version and CMS but As you are using `composer` I'm guessing you are on Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/164#note_65206 there's a patch available.